# Rotating Particle System Emitters

Tags: particles

I have created a galaxy with a circle that is emitting particles and using force-fields to make them go in spiral form, I have used key frames so during the animation at a certain point when the galaxy is in a spiral shape the particles stop moving.

[image: galxy]

Now I want to slowly rotate this galaxy, but I can't seem to do it. I tried rotating the emitter object (a circle) and all the objects to but that didn't work. How do you rotate the entire emitter with the particle system? (or I'm doing something terribly wrong)

Comment: I feel I'm missing the point, but have you tried allowing the formed galaxy particles to "fall" onto or stick to a plane which can be rotated when all particles are in position?